# Xwindows Intrinsics - print type String in 'C'

Tags: c, string, x11

```
Language  'C', **not** C++
Environment Xwindows Intrincics & Athena (Xt, Xaw)
```

I want to use the value from a asciiTextWidget in a 'C' print statement. The type of the value is "String", which is a typedef of 'char *'.

```
String argName, argTask, sinceWhen;

XtVaGetValues(b_txt_21, XtNstring, &argTask ,NULL);
if (strlen(argTask) > 0) {
  printf ("--New argTask\n");
  XtVaSetValues(t_txt_21, XtNstring, argTask ,NULL);
  XtVaSetValues(b_txt_21, XtNstring, "" ,NULL);
}
printf ("++Commit:gets done <%s> <%s>\n", argName,argTask);
```

This produces:

```
--New argTask
++Commit:gets done <> <>
```

I can not find a converter for String->cstring. Nor documentation of the structure at the end of the String's pointer.

Solved:

### XtVaGetValues sets the String correctly.  Apparently XtVaSetValues clears the String content  after setting the widget. Save your copy immediately after the 'get'.